# Slackware 15: Google Authenticator configuration issue / Access Denied

Tags: linux, sshd, pam, slackware, google-authenticator

I am trying to install Google Authenticator on Slackware 15 and I seem to be stuck.

My steps were:

1. Installed google authenticator
2. Added in /etc/pam.d/ssh the following line at the top of the file

> auth required pam_google_authenticator.so

3. Added at the bottom of /etc/ssh/sshd_config the following line

> KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes

4. Install Google Authenticator on my phone
5. Ran google-authenticator and answered as following

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtR9S.png)

6. Restarted sshd

Still, when trying to login through ssh I get access denied

```
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
| Password:
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Access denied
Keyboard-interaction authentication prompts from server:
| Password:
```

I am adding also the configuration of my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file as following:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
UsePAM yes
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
```

And also the contents of my /etc/pam.d/sshd file

```
auth            include         system-auth
auth            include         postlogin
auth            required        pam_google_authenticator.so
account         required        pam_nologin.so
account         include         system-auth
password        include         system-auth
session         include         system-auth
session         include         postlogin
session         required        pam_loginuid.so
-session        optional        pam_elogind.so
```

Did anyone already install this on Slackware 15? Or does anyone have an advice on this?

Thank you

Comment: If you want assistance your going to need to provide your /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: Hello Ramhound, I have edited my post and added the contents of the sshd_config file and also /etc/pam.d/sshd

Comment: You provided the entire configuration file because it certainly should be longer than a couple lines. I assume your logging into root with a password?